# Linked list traversal doesn't traverse all the way?

Tags: java

A linked list has four nodes like below, i am trying iterate or traverse so i can return each node out like below... but my code just gives me the first node and doesn't get to the rest of them to return...

Cary, USA , Population: 40000

Raleigh, USA , Population: 34300

Apex, USA , Population: 60000

Durham, USA , Population: 34000

```
public T retrieveAll(TableInterface<City, String> inChart) {
    Node tmp = head;
    while(tmp != null) {
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
        return (T) head.getItem();
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace, fix that so the code compiles. Furthermore: you're returning from the method from the very first iteration, obviously it will only return one item. Secondly: you return `T`. How does this relate to all elements?

Comment: You can only return one thing at a time.

Comment: How do you expect to accumulate the data that you are returning? Are you storing the results in a string? If so, you will need a base string to continue appending the node values to and then return that result string only. As it is now, you are stopping your entire function call at the first `return`.

Comment: I figured out that these lines give me the subsequent node one by one
//return (T) tmp.getItem();
//return (T) tmp.getNext().getItem();
return (T) tmp.getNext().getNext().getItem();

Comment: One more thing why do you are passing TableInterface<City, String> inChart here and doing nothing with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method can only return one thing at a time. Your method stops and returns when it hits your `return` statement. To return more than one thing, you have to return it as an `ArrayList` or an array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning in `while` loop. Use some thing like add, to add in the `ArrayList`.

Then at the end return that `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from your method in first iteration that is why you are getting only first Node.

To resolve this you should remove return from while loop and add your node in a collection while iterating and return that collection at the end.